# @tailrec annotated method contains a recursive call not in tail position

Tags: eclipse, scala, recursion, pattern-matching, tail-recursion

Here is an minimal example that demonstrates my problem:

```
@tailrec
def fun(x: Int): Int = {
  val y = x match {
    case 5 => return fun(6)
    case 7 => return fun(6)
    case 6 => 40
    case _ => throw new AssertionError("only 5, 6 and 7 allowed")
  }
  y + 2
}
```

Eclipse complains with the following error message:

```
could not optimize @tailrec annotated method
it contains a recursive call not in tail position
```

There are two recursive calls, both in tail position, as far as I can tell, due to the `return` keyword.

What exactly is Eclipse complaining about? I just don't see it.

Comment: Interestingly, IntelliJ IDEA, does not show any error. but, scala REPL shows the same error as you mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

`return` causes it not to be a tail call.

Use the following instead:

```
@tailrec
def fun(x: Int): Int = x match {
  case 5 => fun(6)
  case 7 => fun(6)
  case 6 => 42
  case _ => throw new AssertionError("only 5, 6 and 7 allowed")
}
```

This is either an implementation bug or has to do with the possibility of `return x` compiling to code that throws a `NonLocalReturnControl` exception in a compilation phase that comes after the one that checks for `tailrec`.